# Get returnValue in ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I just created a controlleradvice in my spring boot application and trying to get return value object in the advice:

```
            @ControllerAdvice
        public class ResponseAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {


            @Override
            public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
                                          Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                          ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                    int status = <from returnValue>;
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.valueOf(status)).body(body);

            }
        }
```

and in my controller:

```
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
```

the logic here is always send 200 status code but inside the response we have actual status code:

```
{
    "headers": {},
    "body": {},
    "statusCode": "NO_CONTENT",
    "statusCodeValue": 201
}
```

So my problem here is I don't know how I should access to returnValue in beforeBodyWrite method using returnType.
When I am debugging in the IDE, I can see returnValue is added to returnType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just tested this. This works fine!

Instead of using returnType, use the response to get the status which is propagated by the controller method on which advice is invoked. I rewrote your beforeBodyWrite just for the part where you are fetching and setting the status. I haven't tested it this time but remember doing this at another instance.

```
@Override
public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
      java.lang.Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
      ServerHttpResponse response) {
    int status = HttpStatus.OK.value();
    if (response instanceof ServletServerHttpResponse) {
      status = ((ServletServerHttpResponse) response).getServletResponse().getStatus();
    }
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.valueOf(status)).body(body);
}
```

Comment: ServerHttpRequest never can be converted to ServletServerHttpResponse. If you open the class definition you will see.

Comment: you have to cast ServerHttpResponse to ServletServerHttpResponse, not the request.

Comment: I meant ServletServerHttpResponse, it is not convertable.

Comment: what do you mean? what i provided is the working code up there. Only thing i can think can be confusing is we talking about different classes. The classes i used in my code are org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse and  org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.

Comment: ServerHttpResponse doesn't have getStatus, so when you cast it to ServletServerHttpResponse always getStatus is 200 as long as you don't have exception. For example if ep returns return: new Response(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT); still you will get 200 not 201.

Comment: just curious... did you try running the code or just talking theoretically? if you haven't run the code yet, highly suggest that you run it quickly and test. BTW, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT is 204, not 201. I tested this code with 400 and 404 status. Will try with 204 later and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, I assume you need controller to send 200 always and wrap the actual body, header, status codes in an object and send as a response.

here is a way to go about it

Have a custom object to wrap your response

```
public class MyResponse {
    Map<String, String> headers;
    Object body;
    String statusCode;
    int statusCodeValue;

    public MyResponse(Map<String, String> headers, Object body, String statusCode, int statusCodeValue) {
        this.headers = headers;
        this.body = body;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.statusCodeValue = statusCodeValue;
    }
}
```

Just create and return wrapper object from your controller

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public MyResponse getUsers() {
    int statusValue = 200;
    List<User> users;
    try {
        users = service.getUser();
    }
    catch (UserNotFoundException ex) { statusValue = 404; }
    catch (ActionNotAllowedException ex) { statusValue = 401; }
    catch (Exception ex) { statusValue = 500;}

    return new MyResponse(getHeaders(), users, statusValue, HttpStatus.valueOf(statusValue))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It would be consider as a solution. But here I want to know how we can use ReturnType to get returnValue.